# didUpdateToLocation called only twice on 3G

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, google-maps

the problem is when i turn internet connection from wifi to 3G, location does not updating and did Update To Location is never called.anyone can help me? i have to send updated current location to server through web service after every 5 seconds.web service is calling but every time the same coordinates goes to server.i want to send coordinates of updated location but on 3G the location update method never called when i change location

```
[mapview animateToLocation:newLocation.coordinate];
Currentmarkers.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
deleg.currentCoordinates = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

Following is the code which i used to create location manager :

```
currentLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
currentLocation.distanceFilter  = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
currentLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
currentLocation.delegate = self;
[currentLocation startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: This code is not relavent to your problem.

Comment: The context is really missing in the question. Since the location already be obtained GPS then changing to 3G will not trigger a location change. This makes sense since GPS is not related to 3G/WiFi.

Comment: i have to send updated current location to server through web service after every 5 seconds.web service is calling but every time the same coordinates goes to server.i want to send coordinates of updated location but on 3G the location update method never called when i change location

Comment: show more relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from WiFi to 3G should not have anything to do with it.

You need to post your code that creates the location manager, configures it, sets you up as the delegate, as well as your location manager delegate methods. If you have the desiredAccuracy or the distanceFilter values set high enough, you won't get notified until you move quite a distance.

Try setting the accuracy to the "best" value, and the distance filter value to kCLDistanceFilterNone for testing.

You may also need to add a scrolling text view to your interface that logs location updates, and then take your device and go for a walk of a kilometer or so. Then you should move var enough to be sure to get location updates.